# Guzzle request header

Tags: 8

I'm currently working with Drupal 8's Guzzle HTTP Client.

What I need is the request headers, response headers and the response data (raw html).

Response headers and response data is not the problem:

```
$client = \Drupal::httpClient();
$response = $client->get('https://www.drupal.org');
$responseHeaders = $response->getHeaders(); //Response Headers array
$body = $response->getBody()->getContents(); // Raw HTML
```

But what's the way to get the request headers?

I can find a way in documentation of GuzzleHttp version 4 (https://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/guzzle4/http-messages.html) but nothing like this in version 6 (which is being used by Drupal 8).

Comment: http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/response.html#response-headers

Comment: Well, this is Guzzle version 3 and your link points to the response headers. That's what I already have (as you can see in my post :)) But thanks anyway!

Comment: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-responses  From this version 6 doc, I dont see a similar method. Although creating such a method yourself, shouldn't be terribly difficult ...

Comment: I think you need to inject Middleware to be able to get access to the Request. The docs are pretty bad about describing Middleware and Handlers despite how verbose that page is. Or, if you're just needing to do it during an error, then the RequestException has a getRequest method.

Comment: I would need the whole request header. As injecting Middleware without a good doc seems to be very time intensive for me I will use curl now.